# How to reinitialise Pipe in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-pipe

How can I reinitialise Pipe in Angular 4?

I have a component which uses a Pipe.

Component render once with some data which uses Pipe.

Some data was changed, and Pipe will be changed.

How can I reinitialise pipe or reinitialise Component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipes have attribute `pure`.

`Pure and Impure Pipes`

Pure Pipes are not changed (are immutable).

Impure Pipes will be changed (are mutable).

`@Pipe({ name: 'join', pure: false || true })`

Answer (score 0):

In [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)), a `pipe` can be used as `pure` and `impure`.

**What is a pure and an impure pipe?**

In simple words, `impure-pipe` works even when the array items are changed and `pure-pipe` works only the `component` is loaded.

#### How can I make a pipe pure or impure?

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'sort',
  pure: true | false // true makes it pure and false makes it impure
})
export class myPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return null;
  }

}
```

#### [Click for an awesome demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sorting-with-pipe)

Read more at *[Transforming Data Using Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)*.

Comment: If you had given me a chance to reply then you wouldn't down-vote it. Nothing is copy-pasted. I spent an hour or more to create this demo and gave answer to your question and you simply said 'it's copy paste' and down-voted without asking for clarification.

Comment: Now demo is working, a deleted file was giving error

Comment: If you think my demo is copy-paste, then let me know I would give you 1000 of my repu. It's sure I'll if you prove it